# Remove any specific html code using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the past I used Google Developer Console to delete some specific divs on a page. I could do it manually of course but in some cases where the divs where many I had to use the console. I had a single line code that did the job (I found it while searching the internet) but I lost my note.

So how can I delete using javascript any html code (by  copy pasting the code).

Something like:

```
elements = $('<div ... </div>');
elements.remove();
```

**OR**

```
$('<div  ... </div>').remove();
```

Any ideas? I am not an expert in javascript (obviously) and I've been searching stackoverflow for hours without finding anything that works.

**UPDATE**: I think some people might get confused with my question. Google developer console accepts javascript command lines. So even though I ask for javascript I will use the code on the google developer console.

**UPDATE 2** :

Here is an example of a div I need to delete. Keep in mind I want to copy paste the entire code in the javascript code. **Not** just identify the div.

```
<div class="entry-status-overlay" data-entry-status="declined">
            <div class="entry-status-overlay__inner">
                <span class="entry-status-overlay__title">Declined</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It's the data-entry-status="declined" that makes that div unique so I can't just identify the div using an id selector or a class selector. I need to put the entrire thing there and remove it.

I tried:

```
$('<div class="entry-status-overlay" data-entry-status="declined"><div class="entry-status-overlay__inner"><span class="entry-status-overlay__title">Declined</span></div></div>').remove();
```

It didn't remove the div.

Comment: If you used chrome, you can press the up-cursor key in the dev console to get all the previous entries - if it's not been cleared, you might be lucky.

Comment: $('div').remove() will do, but be more specific by using class selector or id selector, otherwise it removes all div elements
Eg; $('div.notes').remove()

Comment: No id selector .. Just copy paste the a specific code as some divs have the same id so it will delete them as well and I don't want this. I need to copy paste the code instead of using an id selector.

Comment: It's not clear where the op will be running this code, $ is a reference to jQuery and if it's not used on that page, that will not work.

Comment: he already have $ in his question, so guessing he have a reference to jquery library

Comment: OP is looking for a "raw html" selector, which doesn't exist at the moment.

Comment: The only way to remove elements through script is to use a specific selector (classes or id's), so it knows what to delete when you run the .remove()..

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/remove/ is the correct jQuery function to use. The issue I assume is how to select the right divs? You mentioned "some specific divs" but didn't tell us how you are identifying them. You need to use a CSS selector which will grab the right element(s), e.g. an ID or class or some other attribute which the divs have in common. For instance `$(".someCSSClass").remove();` removes all elements with the "someCSSClass" class . https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ gives an overview of the various kinds of selectors available to you.

Comment: If you have no other option, the least you could do instead of deleting manually is, just added a specific class now to your code (something like "delete-this-div") and then you can use the $('.delete-this-div').remove(). This is still better as you don't have to manually select the start to end/closing divs and delete them

Comment: I am so confused guys. Isn't there an option to just paste the code? Please see UPDATE 2 for clarification.

Comment: @Mdermez no there isn't because doing that just selects a new HTML string, it doesn't identify something which is already on the page. I don't know what you did before you lost your code but it can't have been that. Re your update, I have written an answer which I think addresses the requirement to look for divs with a particular attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to search the dom by its outerHTML.

```
function deleteDomByHtml(html){
    html=html.replace(/\s/g,'');
    $("*").each(function(){
       if(this.outerHTML.replace(/\s/g,'')===html){
           $(this).remove();
       }
    });
}
```

And try this line on this page:

```
deleteDomByHtml(`<span class="-img _glyph">Stack Overflow</span>`);
```

Comment: Overkill at its best.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do by simply pasting the code. That will remove all the div element.

You may need a specific selector like `id`,`class` or `child to specific parent` to remove the element from the dom.

Consider this case the divs have common class but the data-entry-status is different. So you can get the dom using a selector and then check the dataset property.

For demo I have put it inside setTimeout to show the difference. In application you can avoid it

```js
setTimeout(function() {

  document.querySelectorAll('.entry-status-overlay').forEach(function(item) {
    let getStatus = item.dataset.entryStatus;
    if (getStatus === 'declined') {
      item.remove()
    }
  })
}, 2000)
```

```html
<div class="entry-status-overlay" data-entry-status="declined">
  <div class="entry-status-overlay__inner">
    <span class="entry-status-overlay__title">Declined</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="entry-status-overlay" data-entry-status="accepted">
  <div class="entry-status-overlay__inner">
    <span class="entry-status-overlay__title">accepted</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: SIr. Thank you for your input. Trust me I had the code in the past and it was working - I just lost my note :( . The thing is that using id or class will remove wrong divs. But by using a specific code that contains unique information will delete the right stuff.

Comment: @Mdermez " using id or class will remove wrong divs"...an ID must be unique to a single element, so it's hard to see how that would remove the wrong thing, as long as you gave the right ID. A class might select too many things, potentially, that's certainly true. But there are plenty of ways to restrict it using a more complex selector, or things like .find() or .parents() etc etc etc.

Comment: what he meant by wrong divs is "the divs he didn't want to remove"

Comment: Sir you're right on the id part. Unfortunately the website that I am looking to apply the code has classes instead of ids and as you can see in my second update it's some other information in that div that makes it unique. It's like an image overlay which is the same on all images. So I need to delete that overlay in order to see the content behind it.

Comment: &('<div class="entry-status-overlay" data-entry-status="declined"><div class="entry-status-overlay__inner"><span class="entry-status-overlay__title">Declined</span></div></div>').remove()

Comment: As you can see at the solution I was able to just paste the code :) . Thank you so much for your input though.

Answer (score 1):

Just add any attribute with `[]` and it will remove the element.

```js
$('[class="entry-status-overlay"]').remove();
/*OR*/
$('[data-entry-status="declined"]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-status-overlay" data-entry-status="declined">
            <div class="entry-status-overlay__inner">
                <span class="entry-status-overlay__title">Declined</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function del(){
   var h =  document.body.outerHTML; 
   h = h.match('<div>...</div>');
   h.length--;
   return h;
}
```

I guess this will work just give it a try... i tried on browser console and it worked, this way you can match the exact  you want.

Comment: Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

I might as well add my take on this. Try running this in your console and see the question vanish.

```
// convert the whole page into string
let thePage = document.body.innerHTML,
string = [].map.call( thePage, function(node){
return node.textContent || node.innerText || "";
}).join("");

// I get some string. in this scenario the Question or you can set one yourself
let replacableCode = document.getElementsByClassName('post-layout')[0].innerHTML,
string2 = [].map.call( replacableCode, function(node){
return node.textContent || node.innerText || "";
}).join("");

// replace whole page with the removed innerHTML string with blank
document.body.innerHTML = thePage.replace(replacableCode,'');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to identify divs with that particular data attribute, you can use a data-attribute selector. In the example below, I've used a button and click event to make the demo more visual, but in the console the only line you'd need would be:

```
$('div[data-entry-status="declined"]').remove();
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#testbutton").click(function() {
    $('div[data-entry-status="declined"]').remove();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-status-overlay" data-entry-status="declined">
            <div class="entry-status-overlay__inner">
                <span class="entry-status-overlay__title">Declined</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="x">Some other div</div>
        <button type="button" id="testbutton">Click me to test removing the div</button>
```

See https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ for documentation of attribute selectors.

P.S. Your idea to paste some raw HTML into the jQuery constructor and then execute "remove" on it cannot work - you're telling jQuery to create an object based on a HTML string, which is, as far as it's concerned, a *new* set of HTML. It does not try to match that to something existing on the page, even if that exact HTML is in the DOM somewhere, it pays it no attention. It treats what you just gave it as being totally independent. So then when you run .remove() on that new HTML...that HTML was never added to the page, so it cannot be removed. Therefore .remove() has no effect in that situation.

Comment: Actually my idea worked. Please see the accepted answer. This is what I was looking for. I just pasted the desired code.

Comment: @Mdermez good, but what's in the accepted answer is a rather different method to what you said in the question had been your code. You're very expensively traversing every single element in the whole DOM to find things with a literal string match to your HTML string. It'll work but it's not very efficient compared to using a proper selector. In a big document it might take some time. I assume it was you who downvoted my answer? I realise it's not precisely the methodology you wanted to use, but would you like to clarify how/why it fails to meet the same requirement albeit by a different route?

Comment: I always do things rationally. The reason I downvoted your answer is just because it didn't work as it should and you can see it from you own script. When you hit the button "declined" stays there when it should be removed. The accepted answer is not different from what I asked. I specifically said in "UPDATE 2" that I need to put the whole code there and not just a part of it. The reason is that while the  data-entry-status="declined makes the div unique .. by removing just this won't remove the whole div. Your reply on this can be "why you didn't delete the div using the class selector?"

Comment: The reason is that many divs had the same class while some of them had the status that made them unique. So I wanted to be able to just paste the code I needed to be deleted. Perhaps an "exact-match" clarification would be more helpful for you and others. I am sorry I didn't mention this but I thought it was clear enough that I needed to just paste any code I wanted. Thank you though for your input.

Comment: @Mdermez " When you hit the button "declined" stays there when it should be removed."...no, it doesn't. It disappears. I'm using the latest version of Chrome. What browser are you viewing this page with? Do you get an error in the snippet's console or anything?

Comment: @Mdermez " the data-entry-status="declined makes the div unique .. by removing just this won't remove the whole div"...what do you mean by the "whole" div? You mean there is some HTML outside this which also needs to be removed? You didn't show it in the question, it there is. I assume you realise that if we remove the outer div with the "data-entry-status" attribute, then all the HTML elements which are its children are also automatically removed at the same time